# Extract from Azure DevOps analytics a snapshot of sprint planning hours

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-analytics

I need to take a snapshot of the Azure DevOps analytics that gives me the number of hours predicted on the sprint planning date. If possible, grouped by parent ID.

I will also need a second view, grouping by activity, but starting from the first I believe I can reach the second.

Below is an attempted consultation, but it didn't work out very well. It returns an error message that I cannot understand why.

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_odata/v3.0-preview//WorkItemSnapshot?$filter=(DateValue ge Iteration/StartDate and DateValue le Iteration/StartDate and WorkItemType eq 'Task')/groupby((Activity), aggregate($count as Count, RemainingWork with sum as WorkTotal))
```

Error:

> {"error":{"code":"0","message":"VS403483: The query specified in the
> URI is not valid: ')' or ',' expected at position 136 in '(DateValue
> ge Iteration/StartDate and DateValue le Iteration/StartDate and
> WorkItemType eq 'Task')/groupby((Activity), aggregate($count as Count,
> RemainingWork with sum as
> RemainingWorkTotal))'..","innererror":{"message":"')' or ',' expected
> at position 136 in '(DateValue ge Iteration/StartDate and DateValue le
> Iteration/StartDate and WorkItemType eq 'Task')/groupby((Activity),
> aggregate($count as Count, RemainingWork with sum as
> RemainingWorkTotal))'.","type":"Microsoft.OData.ODataException","stacktrace":""}}}

**Complementing my need, I need to obtain the values that are highlighted in yellow in the image below:**

https://ibb.co/WfHdtBq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use "$apply=filter" instead of "$filter=". $apply triggers aggregation behavior. It takes a sequence of set transformations, separated by forward slashes to express that they are consecutively applied, i.e. the result of each transformation is the input to the next transformation. Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/odata-supported-features?view=azure-devops#aggregation-extensions-support).

In addition, I think you can use `DateValue le Iteration/EndDate` instead of `DateValue le Iteration/StartDate`. `DateValue ge Iteration/StartDate` means begin trend at Iteration start and `DateValue le Iteration/EndDate` means end trend at Interation end. You can refer to the [sample reports-OData query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-sprintburndown?view=azure-devops&tabs=odata).

Here is my query and it works on my side:

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItemSnapshot?
$apply=filter(
    DateValue ge Iteration/StartDate 
    and DateValue le Iteration/EndDate 
    and WorkItemType eq 'Task'
    )
    /groupby(
        (Activity), 
    aggregate($count as Count, RemainingWork with sum as WorkTotal)
    )
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Walter! His expression also worked on my side. I was using StartDate because I need to get the load of hours from the beginning of the sprint, regardless of the evolution.

A complementary question: instead of using Iteration / StartDate to filter a period, I informed a range of dates, and noticed that WorkTotal is always returned null.

The information I need to extract from DevOps is the total number of hours estimated by the team at the end of the day of the planning meeting. How should I create my query to obtain this information?

Comment: I linked an image in the post. Looking at the DevOps burndown, the information I need is Remaining and Remaining Capacity from the first day of the sprint. I highlighted these two information in the image of this link: https://ibb.co/WfHdtBq. Is it possible to create a query to get this information by sprint? The ideal for my need is to have this information, at least remaining work for each Backlog item (PBI or Bug).

Comment: Here is a sample about [Burndown by Tasks' Remaining Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-boards-sprintburndown?view=azure-devops&tabs=odata#burndown-by-tasks-remaining-work). Does it meet your needs?

Comment: Hi @Walter Qian-MSFT ! Thanks for your help. Sorry for the late answer. I ran the example mentioned, but it still doesn't return the information I need. I need to obtain from DevOps analytics two values for each sprint: the team's total hours capacity and the total hours estimated by the team. When looking at the DevOps burndown report, I need to get a snapshot of the first day of the sprint. How should the filter in WorkItemSnapshot be to reach these values? See this image [link](https://ibb.co/WfHdtBq), these are the two values I highlighted in yellow.